# Highlight text in a pdf file embedded in a site using C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, webbrowser-control

I need to render pdf file in a webbrowser then highlight some words on it.
How can i do it? any sure 3rd party dll that i can use for this?

Thank,

Jepe

Comment: In a web browser *without the adobe reader plug-in* I suppose?

Comment: with or without. is that recommended? or do you have other means? i just need to display the pdf file with the highlighted words on it

Answer (score 0):

I am using "URL Parameters" as in [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) to get to a certain PDF Page or bookmark. There is something for highlighting too, but not searching and highlighting AFAIK. I also do have some issue ([see Fragment lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033589/fragment-anchor-in-net-4-webbrowser-control-getting-lost-with-adobe-pdf-read) ) using it with the WinForm WebBrowser control, nevertheless I find the approach useful.